# Determining the encoding of a file on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, encoding, character-encoding

How can I determine the character encoding of plain text files (such as HTML) on Mac OS X?

Comment: There is a similar thread on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539294/how-do-i-determine-file-encoding-in-osx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting the encoding of a text file (Mac OS X)](http://superuser.com/questions/151981/converting-the-encoding-of-a-text-file-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`file -I {filename}` worked from the [link Ayaz provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539294/how-do-i-determine-file-encoding-in-osx). Apparently though, [there is no definite way to determine the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file/90956#90956).