# Converting the encoding of a text file (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, conversion, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert multiple files to UTF-8 encoding using *nix command line tools?](https://superuser.com/questions/16672/how-can-i-convert-multiple-files-to-utf-8-encoding-using-nix-command-line-tools)

Okay, now that I can [detect the encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/151972/determining-the-encoding-of-a-file-on-mac-os-x), I know that my encoding is using `charset=iso-8859-1` instead of utf. How can I convert this?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use iconv:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 < file > file.new
```

Comment: Ok, that might make sense indeed (though such straightforward answers are found in the other questions too). No need for the `<` by the way.

Comment: @Arjan Note that Google points to this answer first..

Comment: I did this.. now that file was completly emptied....... and I don't have any backup of it.. great..........

Comment: @OZZIE then I am afraid you did it wrong

Comment: To clarify: should that be `<file>` (no spaces) as in "substitute your filename here", or; are you redirecting the output with `>` and the preceding `<` is an error? There is a suggested edit (as well as the first comment) which suggests removing the `<`. I guess this is due to the spaces around `file` inside the `<...>` making it look confusing and as if the `<` is a typo. What increases the confusion is that the second `file.new` does not have `<...>`. You might want to fix that. I'd suggest that `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <filename> <filename>.new` is better... at least it's consistant

Comment: @Greenonline: Both `<` and `>` are intentional – they redirect input from `file` and output into `file.new`. The input redirection is optional since iconv could read its input directly, but I wanted it to be present for consistency.

Comment: You should add your comment to the answer, as it may be interesting to the uninitiated about the input redirection being optional - maybe show both forms of the command line, up to you. Nevertheless, the command line looks better now... :-)

Comment: take note that `file.new` *MUST NOT BE* the same as `file`, otherwise the result will indeed be an empty file